# Excel. Summing costs based on week and cost code

Tags: excel

I'm building a sheet where we track cost every day by individual contractor.

We have specific accounting codes for each type of contractor, but in many cases there are multiple contractors of the same type (ie. mechanical).

For tracking individual daily tickets its best to allow the person inputting the data to add rows (new contractor) as they see fit.

However i'd like to have a summary sheet which would outline the spend by accounting code, for each week of the project.

I tried pivot tables, and SUMIF but can't get it to work so it would be somewhat dynamic, regardless of how many rows get added (really max 100).

[image: daily input data]

[image: weekly summary]

Comment: why isn't the SUMIF working?

Comment: I tried doing SUMIF but i think its failing because i need to sum Sun-Sat of the whole week for each row where the code is the same and its messing up that way? I can get it to work on a single column but not 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the SUMPRODUCT formula instead of SUMIF.  Let's say your accounting codes and are in column A of Sheet1, your amounts are in columns B through F of Sheet1 and your summary is in Sheet2.  You can use `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A1)*Sheet1!B:F)`.

You can adjust as needed for column and sheet names, but that should do the trick.